# java: how to mock Calendar.getInstance()?

Tags: java, date, junit, calendar, mocking

In my code I have something like this:

```
private void doSomething() {
   Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
   ....
}
```

How can I "mock" it in my junit test to return a specific date?

Comment: That line couldn't be compiling!

Comment: Is `today` a class member (field) or a local variable inside a method?

Comment: local variable inside a method

Comment: The modern version of the same question (with answer): [Writing and testing convenience methods using Java 8 Date/Time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956373/writing-and-testing-convenience-methods-using-java-8-date-time-classes)

Comment: Update… FYI, the terrible `Calendar` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: You can fake a clock with the `static` methods on the [`java.time.Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) class. Pass the faked `Clock` instance to the various methods on various `java.time.*` classes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I see it you have three sensible options:

1. Inject the `Calendar` instance in whatever method/class you set that day in.

   `private void method(final Calendar cal) 
   {
       Date today = cal.getTime();
   }`
2. Use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) instead of `Calendar`. This is less an option and more a case of a suggestion as JodaTime will make your life a lot easier. You will still need to inject this time in to the method.

   `DateTime dt = new DateTime();`

   `Date jdkDate = dt.toDate();`
3. Wrap `Calendar` inside some interface that allows you to fetch the time. You then just mock that interface and get it to return a constant `Date`.

   `Date today = calendarInterfaceInstance.getCurrentDate()`

Comment: Joda Time's `DateTimeUtils` class has static methods that set the current time for all other Joda Time objects. This is very useful to set the time to a certain moment, for example for testing.

Comment: @Jesper - Yes that is true and a good point I neglected to mention

Comment: Thank you guys. I followed ur suggestions and I moved to JodaTime. BTW it fixes easily the problem with something like: DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(new DateTime(2012, 2, 14, 13, 43, 21).getMillis());

Answer (score 29):

You can mock it using PowerMock in combination with Mockito:

On top of your class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassThatCallsTheCalendar.class})
```

The key to success is that you have to put the class where you use Calendar in PrepareForTest instead of Calendar itself because it is a system class. (I personally had to search a lot before I found this)

Then the mocking itself:

```
mockStatic(Calendar.class);
when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(calendar);
```

Comment: which dependencies do you include to get mockStatic() method work?

Comment: Sorry I should have said that. I used import static to import the mockStatic method of PowerMockito. See this dependency for powermock mockito: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2/1.6.6

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: +1 , but for the second part, both lines could be simplified to: `PowerMockito.whenNew(Calendar.getInstance()).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(MY_INSTANCE_OBJECT_TO_FEED);`

Comment: @GoGoris Do you mind updating the answer to show where exactly those annotations and PowerMockito calls go inside your test class.

Answer (score 12):

Don't mock it - instead introduce a method you can mock that gets dates. Something like this:

```
interface Utility {

    Date getDate();
}

Utilities implements Utility {


    public Date getDate() {

        return Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

}
```

Then you can inject this into your class or just use a helper class with a bunch of static methods with a load method for the interface:

```
public class AppUtil {

    private static Utility util = new Utilities();

    public static void load(Utility newUtil) {

         this.util = newUtil;
    }

    public static Date getDate() {

        return util.getDate();
    }

}
```

Then in your application code:

```
private void doSomething() {
   Date today = AppUtil.getDate();
   ....
}
```

You can then just load a mock interface in your test methods.

```
@Test
public void shouldDoSomethingUseful() {
     Utility mockUtility = // .. create mock here
     AppUtil.load(mockUtility);

     // .. set up your expectations

     // exercise the functionality
     classUnderTest.doSomethingViaAPI();

     // ... maybe assert something 

}
```

See also [Should you only mock types you own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906344/should-you-only-mock-types-you-own) and [Test smell - everything is mocked](http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html)

Answer (score 6):

Using Mockito and PowerMockito:

```
Calendar endOfMarch = Calendar.getInstance();
endOfMarch.set(2011, Calendar.MARCH, 27);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
Mockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(endOfMarch);
```

Refer to the [link](https://github.com/7droids/PowerMock/blob/master/PowerMock/test/src/de/sevendroids/java/powermock/sample/PowerMockSampleClassWithStaticMethodTest.java) for the complete code.

Answer (score 2):

Write a class called `DateHelper` with a method `getCalendar` that returns `Calendar.getInstance()`.  Refactor the class that you're testing so that it has a member variable of type `DateHelper`, and a constructor that injects that member variable.  Use that constructor in your test, to inject a mock of `DateHelper`, in which `getCalendar` has been stubbed to return some known date.

Answer (score 1):

You can mockit using JMockit. Here you can see how you can do it: [Mock Java Calendar - JMockit vs Mockito](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359900/Mock-Java-Calendar-JMockit-vs-Mockito).

Answer (score 1):

With Mockk

```html
 private lateinit var calendar: Calendar

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        calendar = mockk(relaxed = true)
        mockkStatic(Calendar::class)
        every { Calendar.getInstance() } returns calendar
    }

    @Test
    fun `test date when date is less than 16 month is 0`() {
        every { calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] } returns 12
        every { calendar[Calendar.MONTH] } returns 0
        every { calendar[Calendar.YEAR] } returns 2023

      // assert here

    }
```

refer to the link for [mockk](https://mockk.io/) documentation

Comment: In 2023 neither you nor anyone else should want to use (and thereofre also not want to mock) the `Calendar` class. It was a mostly failed attempt to make up for the deficiencies of `Date` and was always cumbersome to work with. Both `Date` and `Calendar` were obsoleted with the release of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) nearly 10 years ago. Among many features java.time comes with the possibility of supplying a clock that you control to the methods that obtain the current time, so you don’t need mocking at all.

Comment: @OleV.V. that's true :) but sometimes you have to deal with legacy codes and legacy frameworks: I have some thymeleaf templates that uses `dates` and thus the good old Calendar :'(

Answer (score 0):

Avoid use `Calendar.getInstance()` and just use `Mockito` methods to return what you like.
For example:

```kotlin
@Test
fun italianLocale_returnsItalianFormatDate() {
    val calendar: Calendar = Mockito.mock(Calendar::class.java)
    Mockito.`when`(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).thenReturn(27)
    Mockito.`when`(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)).thenReturn(2023)
    Mockito.`when`(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)).thenReturn(1)
    val formatted = calendar.toReadableDate()
    assert(formatted == "27/01/2023")
}
```

import Mockito in your gradle file with:

```
testImplementation ("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:x.x.x")
```

or (if you are using groovy)

```
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:x.x.x"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows using Junit 5 and Mockito

```
@Test
public void doSomething() {
    listCalendarParams("now", Calendar.getInstance());
    Calendar fakedCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(2023, Calendar.OCTOBER, 15, 10, 15);
    listCalendarParams("mock", fakedCalendar);
    try (MockedStatic<Calendar> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
        mockedStatic.when(Calendar::getInstance).thenReturn(fakedCalendar);
        //This or any method here using Calendar.getInstance() will be replaced by mock defined above
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        listCalendarParams("evaluated", calendar);
        assertEquals(Calendar.OCTOBER, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        assertEquals(15, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        assertEquals(10, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        assertEquals(15, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }
}

private static void listCalendarParams(String nameOfCal, Calendar calendar) {
    System.out.println(nameOfCal + ":\t" +
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss")
                    .format(calendar.getTime()));
}3
```

Output:

```
now:        2023-11-27T14:00:48 //This will change anytime you run it.
mock:       2023-10-15T10:15:00
evaluated:  2023-10-15T10:15:00
```