# How to Mock ResultSet to not return null in JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Im trying to test a method in a DAO which uses Calendar. This is the test I have so far:

```
@Test
public void testGetElectionInfo() throws SQLException {
    adminDao.getElectionInfo(1);
    verify(mockConn, times(1)).prepareStatement(anyString());
    verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(1)).setInt(anyInt(), anyInt());
    verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(1)).executeQuery();
    verify(mockResultSet, times(2)).next();
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString("name");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getTimestamp("startDate");
    verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getTimestamp("endDate");
}
```

This is the DAO method:

```
public ElectionInfo getElectionInfo(int electionId) {
    ElectionInfo electionInfo = new ElectionInfo();
    try {
        con = sqlConnection.getConnection();

        stmt = con.prepareStatement(NamedQueries.GET_ELECTION_INFO);
        stmt.setInt(1, electionId);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            Timestamp startDate = rs.getTimestamp("startDate");
            Timestamp endDate = rs.getTimestamp("endDate");

            Calendar startCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
            startCalender.setTime(startDate);

            Calendar endCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
            endCalender.setTime(endDate);

            electionInfo.setName(name);
            electionInfo.setStartDate(startCalender);
            electionInfo.setEndDate(endCalender);
        }

        return electionInfo;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't get the election info of the planned elections.", e);
    } finally{
        closeConnection();
    }
    return electionInfo;
}
```

When I run the test, it gives me a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime
```

How can I resolve this issue? Could you please the post the code that solves this issue? That would help me alot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a static method, you need to use PowerMockito.

Comment: Can you tell us which line number did this occur? Can you add two asserts at line 14 and 15 to verify that `startDate` and `endDate` are not `null`?

Comment: `verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getTimestamp("startDate"); ` return something from this call, right now it returns a null causing it to throw a NPE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java: how to mock Calendar.getInstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275840/java-how-to-mock-calendar-getinstance)

Comment: @jbx it occurs in the Dao method at : startCalender.setTime(startDate);

Comment: So `startDate` is probably `null`. Can you confirm it by adding `assert startDate != null` before that line?

Comment: When mocking the `ResultSet`, Mockito is returning `null` as your `startDate` and `endDate`. You need to explicitly tell it what to return. Refer to the answer by @anchreg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line,
`verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getTimestamp("startDate");` mocks the call but doesn't ask the mocking library to return a Timestamp value, and so the library returns null causing it to throw a NPE. Try changing to,

`verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getTimestamp("startDate").thenReturn(new Timestamp(0));` and likewise for the other methods too.

Comment: this did not solve the issue (andReturn didn't work), but when I saw this post, I came up with this:

        when(mockResultSet.getTimestamp("startDate")).thenReturn(new Timestamp(0));
        when(mockResultSet.getTimestamp("endDate")).thenReturn(new Timestamp(0));

And this solved my issue!

Comment: oops! corrected the method name in the answer. thanks for pointing it out! `andReturn` is in EasyMock :)