# How to mock Calendar instance in Java Spring Boot for Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, powermockito

I have a method that I have to test -

```
public class DateUtil {

        public static Date getPreviousDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

This code is part of Spring Boot.

The POM file is given below -

[Pastebin for POM](https://pastebin.com/5CpJQ2Q0)

I want to try mocking it using PowerMockRunner (as mentioned in many resources online) But I cannot seem to import it into my test file.

I tried mocking Mockito but that is also throwing error

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36472441/6424383)

Comment: @gokhanbirincii tried them all. didn't work in my project because somehow I cannot import powermockrunner, even if its specified in POM. Check the POM

Comment: some mockito versions not compatible with powermockito's some versions, you can check versions in [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions)

Comment: @gokhanbirincii tried the latest version by omitting what comes through spring-boot-starter-test and importing the versions speified in your document. Still same error

Comment: Can you show us the test file and the error that is being thrown?

Comment: There is no powermockito library in reference ni Ecipse despite mentioned in POM. So i cant even compile with the solutions shared here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36472441/6424383

Comment: you can override default mockito version like:
`<mockito.version>version here</mockito.version>` add this into properties tag.

Just for proposal you can follow this steps :
1- put into properties compatible version in properties tag.
2- then add this dependencies

Comment: 0) You mention Spring Boot. What impact does it have on testing of this simple utility class) 1) what are you trying to test? Whether java.util.Calendar works fine? It does. 2) There are several methods for testing such code (using PowerMock is one of them, redesigning it to use dependency injection is another). Can you redesign this class or do you have to test it as it is (but first, respond to question 1, please).

Comment: 2-`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>`

Comment: @gokhanbirincii it didnt work

Comment: [this](https://pastebin.com/YMPurtf8) should work. i am currently using this versions.

Comment: @gokhanbirincii i see eclipse actually doesn't detect the package. I'm getting a new error now. I'll paste the stack trace in the morning

Comment: @PrateekNarendra okey

Comment: @gokhanbirincii looks like an eclipse issue.