# JUnit Java Instant dependent tests

Tags: java, junit, java.time.instant

I'm using `Instant.now()` to get the current UTC millis, and then truncate it to the nearest hour. All my `JUnit` are failing because they are taking the current System time. How can I make `Instant.now()` return a fixed value which I could supply in the `JUnit` test.

```
public static Long getCurrentHour() {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant cH = now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    return cH.toEpochMilli();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing and testing convenience methods using Java 8 Date/Time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956373/writing-and-testing-convenience-methods-using-java-8-date-time-classes)

Comment: Not fully, that SO requires the source to have a `setClock` which is not good.

Comment: I thought that the `setClock` *was* good. It makes the class testable. Mileages differ.

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the static method `Instant.now()` to give you a static instant value.
You can use `PowerMockito` for that.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Instant.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Mock private Instant mockInstant;

    @Test
    public void getCurrentHour() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Instant.class);
        when(Instant.now()).thenReturn(mockInstant);
        when(mockInstant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)).thenReturn(mockInstant);
        long expectedMillis = 999l;
        when(mockInstant.toEpochMilli()).thenReturn(expectedMillis);

        assertEquals(expectedMillis, YourClass.getCurrentHour());
    }
}
```