# How shoul I test logic that contains calls to aquire current date?

Tags: java, datetime, kotlin, architecture, software-design

For example, I have this Kotlin class and method (Spring-managed class if it matters):

```kotlin
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import java.time.LocalDateTime

data class TestObj(
    val msg: String,
    val dateTime: LocalDateTime
)

@Service
class TestAnotherService {
    fun doSmthng1(testObj: TestObj) {
        println("Oh my brand new object : $testObj")
    }
}

@Service
class TestService(
    private val testAnotherService: TestAnotherService
) {
    fun doSmthng() {
        testAnotherService.doSmthng1(TestObj("my message!", LocalDateTime.now()))
    }
}
```

How can I test that `TestService` passes `TestObj` with `dateTime` as `LocalDateTime#now`?

I have several solutions:

1. Let's add a small delta in the comparison in the `assertEquals`.
2. Let's verify that in the object that we passing in the `TestAnotherService#doSmthng1` `dateTime` field is not `null` or even use `Mockito#any`.
3. Let's mock call `LocalDateTime#now` using PowerMock or similar.
4. Let's use DI. Create configuration with this bean:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    fun currentDateTime(): () -> LocalDateTime {
        return LocalDateTime::now
    }
}
```

And modify service that using `LocalDateTime#now` to this:

```
    fun doSmthng() {
        testAnotherService.doSmthng1(TestObj("my message!", currentDateTimeFunc.invoke()))
    }
```

5. Just don't. This doesn't worth it to test `LocalDateTime`.

Which is an optimal solution? Or maybe there are other solutions?

Comment: I suggest that you study [Writing and testing convenience methods using Java 8 Date/Time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956373/writing-and-testing-convenience-methods-using-java-8-date-time-classes) and [How to change the value new Date() in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470651/how-to-change-the-value-new-date-in-java). It’s in Java, but I certainly expect it will work in Kotlin too.

Comment: @OleV.V. I see. In those questions, people suggest using DI, or other ways to inject `Clock`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the current date as function parameter.

```
fun doSmthng(now: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()) {
    testAnotherService.doSmthng1(TestObj("my message!", now))
}
```

And in the test you can pass some specific date and assert on it. Idea is to inject the dependencies instead of creating explicitly in the function body.

Comment: Looking good, thanks! This option for me is more suitable, but let's wait for other opinions.