# Mock static method with Kotlin, Spring, Junit5, PowerMock and Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito, powermock, junit5

At class level I have:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@PrepareForTest(LocalDateTime::class)
```

My test method contains this:

```
@Test
fun `testMethod`() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime::class.java)
    Mockito.`when`(LocalDateTime.now()).thenReturn(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 8, 22, 10, 0, 0, 0));
 }
```

My build.gradle.kts

```
testImplementation ( "org.mockito:mockito-core:3.5.9")
testImplementation("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.7")
testImplementation("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit5:1.6.4")
```

The error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> For example:
> when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

How to mock `LocalDateTime.now()` with Kotlin, Junit5, Spring Boot 2, Mockito, and PowerMock?

(I don't want to use LocalDateTime.now(clock) method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How shoul I test logic that contains calls to aquire current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259765/how-shoul-i-test-logic-that-contains-calls-to-aquire-current-date)

Comment: I think, creating function with parameter "now" is a bad idea. Because you perhaps always expecting LocalDateTime.now(), so why to make param for it? If we could mock static methods via `PowerMock`, so why not to use it?

Comment: using `LocalDateTime.now()` directly in the function body is code smell, and has *side effects*. Passing the dependency from outside makes it testable. You can name the method parameter whatever you want

Comment: Ok, you're right. But the question comes down 'How to mock a static method' which does not work.

Comment: check out  `Mockito.mockStatic` on latest mockito version

Comment: In general, no new software should require static calls. In this case, create a `Clock` interface and pass it as a parameter to the class (as Thomas mentioned above). In this way you can build your whole application using this class and have a number of test implementations (e.g. one that always return the same time, another where you can control how much time passes).