# Force the server datetime to a given value, in order to perform a JUnit test that doesn't have the new date as parameter

Tags: java, junit

How can I simulate a certain datetime inside a unit test of my java application, independent from the real date time of the server, such that the application 'believes' that the current datetime is the one I forced and the test can be executed 'as' now would be equal to the datetime I forced?

PS: The question is not duplicated from other question because my test has not the new datetime as parameter, in other words is not something like

```
assertThat(newDate).isEqualTo(someDate);
```

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday: [Force the local datetime to a given value, in order to perform a JUnit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275751/force-the-local-datetime-to-a-given-value-in-order-to-perform-a-junit-test). I have reopened that question since I understand that it was no duplicate. Under your previous question I asked: *Does the comparison you are performing depend on system time? … If not, why are you worrying about it at all?* I still haven’t understood and hence have a hard time making sense of your question.

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate; the other question doesn't use the new datetime as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency injection to pass something into the application that lets you get the date:

```
public class Application {
    public Application(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar = calendar;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        LocalDate today = calendar.todaysDate();
        // Do something based on the date
    }

    private Calendar calendar;
}
```

where `Calendar` is just an abstraction:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public interface Calendar {
    public LocalDate todaysDate();
}
```

For tests, you can have an implementation that returns the date you want:

```
public class FixedDateCalendar implements Calendar {
    @Override
    public LocalDate todaysDate() {
        return LocalDate.of(2022, 5, 1);
    }
}
```

and you pass it into the application:

```
Application myApp = new Application(new FixedDateCalendar());
```

In the production code, you want an implementation that uses the system clock:

```
public class SystemCalendar implements Calendar {
    @Override
    public LocalDate todaysDate() {
        return LocalDate.now();
    }
}
```

and again, this is just wired up:

```
Application myApp = new Application(new SystemCalendar());
```