# Java Testing Calendar by changing current date

Tags: java, junit

I have this fonction:

```
/**
 * @return From november to december -> current year +1 else current year
 */
public static int getCurrentScolYear () {
    int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
    if (  month == NOVEMBER || month == DECEMBER) {
        return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) +1;
    }

    return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

This is used to calculate a scolar year (that start in november).

I would like to test this in a Junit test, by changing the 'current time'. So I can test the result for different dates.

I find this thread but it seems over complicated: [java: how to mock Calendar.getInstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275840/java-how-to-mock-calendar-getinstance)

Is there a simple solution to test this?

Comment: The third option in the accepted answer on the thread you linked isn't overly complicated by any means. Just create a `CalendarProvider` interface, implement a `SystemCalendarProvider`, as well as a testing provider that provides a calendar the test specifies. It's even easier if you're already using dependency injection of some sort in your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *java.time*

The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically `ZonedDateTime`. There is no reason to ever using `Calendar` again.

Below is my replacement for your code.

### Custom class

We could return the type-safe and self-explanatory [`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#now(java.time.Clock)) object rather than a mere integer number. But that would be misleading as that class is explicitly defined as an ISO 8601 compliant year number.

I suggest instead you define your own `AcademicYear` class. Pass around objects of this class to make your code more self-documenting, provide for type-safety, and ensure valid values. Something like the following class.

This custom class also provides a home for your static methods.

This class follows the lead of the `java.time.Year` class, including [its naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html).

An academic year is actually *two* year numbers, the starting year and the following stopping year. The class below stores both.

Example usages:

```
AcademicYear.now().getDisplayName() // 2017-2018
```

or

```
AcademicYear.now().getValueStart() // First year of the two-year range, such as 2018 of the year 2018-2019.
```

I threw this class together without testing. So use this as a guide, not production code.

#### `AcademicYear.java`

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

// This class follows the lead of the `java.time.Year` class.
// See JavaDoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Year.html
// See OpenJDK source-code: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Year.java
// This class follows the immutable objects pattern. So only getter accessor methods, no setters.
public class AcademicYear {
    // Statics
    static public int FIRST_YEAR_LIMIT = 2017;
    static public int FUTURE_YEARS_LIMIT = 10;
    static public Set < Month > academicYearStartingMonths = EnumSet.of( Month.NOVEMBER , Month.DECEMBER );

    // Members
    private int academicYearNumberStart;

    // Constructor
    private AcademicYear ( int academicYearNumberStart ) {
        if ( academicYearNumberStart < AcademicYear.FIRST_YEAR_LIMIT ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Received a year number: " + academicYearNumberStart + " that is too long ago (before " + AcademicYear.FIRST_YEAR_LIMIT + "). Message # c5fd65c1-ed10-4fa1-96db-77d08ef1d97e." );
        }
        if ( academicYearNumberStart > Year.now().getValue() + AcademicYear.FUTURE_YEARS_LIMIT ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Received a year number that is too far in the future, over " + AcademicYear.FUTURE_YEARS_LIMIT + " away. Message # 8581e4ca-afb3-4ab7-8849-9b02c434eb4c." );
        }
        this.academicYearNumberStart = academicYearNumberStart;
    }

    public static AcademicYear of ( int academicYearNumberStart ) {
        return new AcademicYear( academicYearNumberStart );
    }

    public int getValueStart ( ) {
        return this.academicYearNumberStart;
    }

    public int getValueStop ( ) {
        return ( this.academicYearNumberStart + 1 );
    }

    public String getDisplayName ( ) {
        String s = this.academicYearNumberStart + "-" + ( this.academicYearNumberStart + 1 );
        return s;
    }

    // ------| `Object`  |---------------------

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "AcademicYear{ " +
                "academicYearNumberStart=" + academicYearNumberStart +
                " }";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o ) {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        AcademicYear that = ( AcademicYear ) o;
        return this.getDisplayName().equals( that.getDisplayName() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( ) {
        return Objects.hash( this.getDisplayName() );
    }

    // -----------|  Factory methods  |-------------------

    static public AcademicYear now ( ) {  // I think making ZoneId optional is a poor design choice, but I do so here to mimic `java.time.Year`.
        AcademicYear ay = AcademicYear.now( Clock.systemDefaultZone() );
        return ay;
    }

    static public AcademicYear now ( ZoneId zoneId ) {
        // Determine the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
        AcademicYear ay = AcademicYear.now( Clock.system( zoneId ) );
        return ay;
    }

    static public AcademicYear now ( Clock clock ) {
        final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( clock );
        AcademicYear ay = AcademicYear.from( localDate );
        return ay;
    }

    static public AcademicYear from ( LocalDate localDate ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( localDate , "Received a null `LocalDate` object. Message # 558dd5e8-5cff-4c6e-b0f8-40dbcd76a753." );
        // Extract the month of the specified date. If not Nov or Dec, subtract one from the year.
        int y = localDate.getYear();
        // If not November or December, subtract 1.
        int startingYear;
        if ( ! academicYearStartingMonths.contains( localDate.getMonth() ) ) {
            startingYear = ( y - 1 );
        } else {
            startingYear = y;
        }
        AcademicYear ay = AcademicYear.of( startingYear );
        return ay;
    }

}
```

### `ZoneId`

Another change is the required argument for `ZoneId`, a time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date, and therefore a year. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

### Break up methods

Another change, is we have two sets of methods rather than one single method.

One method, `AcademicYear.from`, has responsibility for the logic of making the November adjustment. You pass a `LocalDate` to this method.

The other methods, three variations of `AcademicYear.now`, are responsible for determining the current moment, adjusting to the specified time zone, and extracting a date-only `LocalDate` object. That `LocalDate` object is then passed to the other method.

#### `Clock` for unit-testing

For testing, you can pass to one of the `now` method variations a [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) instance that alters time as you may desire. The `Clock` class provides several clocks with altered behavior, such as fixed-point in time, current moment plus/minus a span-of-time, and altered cadence where the clock ticks in your specified granularity such as every 5 minutes.

For more info on the altered `Clock` behaviors, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26570951/642706) to another Question.

Example:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;  // 2018-01-23
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 ) ; // 8 AM.
Instant instant = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ).toInstant() ;
Clock c = Clock.fixed( instant , z ) ;
AcademicYear ay = AcademicYear.now( c ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you