# doAnswer for static methods - PowerMock

Tags: java, mocking, powermock

One of static method I am using, it does two things. It returns some data, but it also modifies the argument object that is passed to it. This updated argument object is then used later in code.

I am using PowerMock to mock the return behavior.

For defining the second part - updating the input argument, I am defining doAnswer method but it's not working. The method that I'm trying to test looks like this.

```
public void login() throws ConnectionException, AsyncApiException {
    ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();

    //This call sets the value in one member variable 'serviceEndPoint in ParterConfig which is accessed later in this method only.
    partnerConnection = Connector.newConnection(partnerConfig);

    //partnerConfig.getServiceEndpoint is called.

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Connector.class);
    when(Connector.newConnection(Mockito.any(ConnectorConfig.class))).thenReturn(partnerConnection);

    PowerMockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            ConnectorConfig config = (ConnectorConfig) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            config.setServiceEndpoint("service end point");
            return null;
        }
    }).when(Connector.newConnection(Mockito.any(ConnectorConfig.class)));
}
```

but above throws error saying 'Unfinished stubbing detected here'.
`Connector` is a third party class so I don't have control over its behavior.

Any suggestions, what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
PowerMockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    /* ... */
}).when(Connector.newConnection(Mockito.any(ConnectorConfig.class)));
```

Your `when` is the problem. In normal Mockito, using any `doAnswer`/`doReturn`/etc call, you have to place the call you're stubbing *outside* of the call to `when`, like so:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    /* ... */
}).when(yourMock).callVoidMethod();
//            ^^^^^^
```

PowerMockito further requires that calls to static methods happen [in the next statement](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/latest/org/powermock/api/mockito/expectation/PowerMockitoStubber.html#when-java.lang.Class-), like so:

```
PowerMockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    /* ... */
}).when(Connector.class); Connector.newConnection(/*...*/);
//                    ^^^^^^
```

Note that from [2009 (~1.3.x)](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/commit/32b5d26004fb09445c49080c35c2b787a50e43a7#diff-b3541b1aa8477abdb4bd008a5279e594e95cfd6810c4657b2564b48099b3eeefR35) to [2013 (~1.5.x)](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/commit/3f2d9f1985f4a59b22df918386c2c0b4ab3b0348), the docs were actually inconsistent, alluding to a zero-arg `when` despite all signatures requiring at least a class literal.

**Obligatory PSA:** It's generally a good idea to [avoid mocking types you don't own](http://davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html), though [opinions may vary on that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906344/should-you-only-mock-types-you-own).

Comment: thnx for doc link. I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: This worked. I have filed a bug. Subject is not to point but I can't seem to edit it. https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=452&can=4&q=javadoc

Comment: I get 404's for the first 2 links.