# How can I unit test Eclipse Command Handlers?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, mocking, eclipse-rcp, fixtures

I have an Eclipse 3.x-based application which uses commands and handlers.

I'm in the process of upping the code coverage and want to test as much as I can. The simple cases (POJOs) I've learned how to test. However, there are cases where I can't find a good starting point, especially when creating a fixture.

For example: Eclipse Command Handlers. I have a handler class `MyHandler` extending `org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler`. It has a single method `public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException`. Usually, `event` is passed in from a user action in the GUI, e.g., clicking a menu item.

How can I unit test this? Would I need to **mock** the `ExecutionEvent` with the help of a mocking framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless inevitable, I prefer to mock only types I do own. See here for a discussion of [Should you only mock types you own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906344/should-you-only-mock-types-you-own)

Since `ExecutionEvent`s can be created without too much hassle I wouldn't mock them. The snippet below creates an event that you can pass to your handlers' execute method.

```java
IEvaluationContext context = new EvaluationContext( null, new Object() );
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
ExecutionEvent event = new ExecutionEvent( null, parameters, null, context );
```

The first argument of the `ExecutionEvent` constructor references the command - I have never had any use for it. If your code requires an actual command, you can use the `ICommandService` to obtain a reference to your command:

```java
ICommandService commandService = ...
Command command = commandService.getCommand( "id.of.my.command" );
```

The second argument is a map of command parameters. The third argument is the *trigger*. If case of the Eclipse workbench this is the SWT [Event](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FEvent.html) if available. Leave it `null` if your production code does not evaluate it.

Before calling execute, you would probably want to prepare the variables of the `context`:

```java
context.addVariable( ISources.ACTIVE_PART_NAME, myPart );
context.addVariable( ISources.ACTIVE_CURRENT_SELECTION_NAME, new StructuredSelection() );
```

Note that `null` is not allowed as a variable value. Either omit the call or - if already added, use `removeVariable()`.

If you don't need a command (see above) - and of course your production code doesn't require a workbench - you can even run the tests as plain JUnit tests (as opposed to PDE JUnit test).

Comment: Thank you. Although this isn't mentioned in my question, could you also hint at how to process the `activeWorkbenchWindow` in such a test? E.g., I'm using `HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).close()` at some point, which throws an NPE...

Comment: Not sure what 'process' means here. The NPE is because the active WorkbenchWindow is `null`. To add it to your test context, you'd write `context.addVariable( ISources.ACTIVE_WORKBENCH_WINDOW_NAME, PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow() )`. If you already have a workbench part or the like at hand, I recommend to reference the WorkbenchWindow from there, e.g. part.getSite().getPage().getWorkbenchWindow()