# Mock SWT Printer

Tags: java, testing, swt

I am in the progress of writing some code that prints on an `org.eclipse.swt.printing.Printer`. So first step is to see how I can test this, but it seems the architecture doesn't allow me to define my own printer, since neither `PrinterData` nor `Printer` are interfaces as they should, or at least an abstract class.

I could probably just mock the `GC` object that gets printed on, but this would be really hard since I use a third-party library to do the actual printing. (And to be honest, `GC` objects are not the best for unit tests.)

Or I could just test the models before they get printed, however there is still a big step missing in the test.

Is there a way to mock a `Printer` so I can test my code fully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually mock only types that I own ([Should you only mock types you own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906344/should-you-only-mock-types-you-own)).

Now that it is even technically near-impossible to mock final types like `Printer`, I would write a printer abstraction. This class would only expose the printer API that the application actually relies on. Internally the abstraction could use an instance of `Printer` to delegate to.

This leaves you with a class or interface that is safe to mock and only the delegation code would be untested.