# How to handle unreachable Exceptions with TDD

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

I'm still getting my head around parts of TDD. I've got a new library I'm writing so this seems like a good opportunity to try it out.

What I've read on TDD advertises 100% code coverage, but that seems a bit ivory tower, so I configured JaCoco to require 90% code coverage to give me some breathing room.

I started out on the code that loads the KeyStore. There's lots of boiler plate code and lots of checked exceptions. So starting here makes my life easier down the road. Everything looks good, and my tests are passing. But code coverage is only at 49%. Looking through the code, everything is covered except for what I'd call "Impossible Exceptions" like this one:

```
public void saveKey(Key key, String alias) {
    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry entry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(new SecretKeySpec(key.getMaterial(), "AES"));

    try {
        keyStore.setEntry(alias, entry, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new UnexpectedErrorException("Failed to save the key", e);
    }
}
```

In this particular case, according to the docs, KeyStoreException is thrown if the keyStore hasn't been initialized. I'm coding defensively and have guaranteed that the keyStore will be initialized at this point. So the KeyStoreException cannot be thrown. But it's a checked exception so I have to deal with it, so I'm wrapping it in a custom RuntimeException.

Problem is I have no way to trigger this error in my unit tests. In fact I've done everything I can to make sure that it won't happen.

Given cases like this how does TDD achieve a mythical 100% coverage?

I could mock KeyStore, but advice from Mockito is "Don't mock types you don't own." So I'd rather not. Also KeyStore relies a couple static methods where Mockito doesn't help, and I don't want to bring in PowerMock for a simple case, and I'm not that convinced that throwing more libraries at the problem is an ideal solution.

So:

- Is TDD's 100% code coverage mythical?
- Is there a technique to get code analysis to recognize this code as covered?

My anticipated solution for now is to move my configured 90% code coverage restriction down to 40 or 50 percent until I have more classes to bring my over-all average coverage up. But before I do that is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you only mock types you own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906344/should-you-only-mock-types-you-own)

Comment: Stick the following line in a separate method: `KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry entry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(new SecretKeySpec(key.getMaterial(), "AES"));` and mock that method to throw `KeyStoreException`

Comment: @alfasin: You mean mock the class that is under test? I was under the impression you should only mock a class's dependencies. Not the class itself.

Comment: I'm curious, who makes these "rules" ? I mock whatever I see fit according to the situation I'm in. When I'm having hard time (unit) testing something it's usually a red flag that something should be refactored. In your case you can wrap that dependency with a method and mock that method to generate the requested behavior for the test. If you'll show me good reasoning why it's a bad idea I'll thank you for teaching me something new!

Comment: Fairly stated! In this case I'm leaning on Mockito's expertise. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests
The gist of it is there is no guarantee your stubbed logic will behave the same as the actual library. So if you don't control how/when the behavior will change you shouldn't mock it. Also in this case, this is the class I'm trying to wrap away this mess. So wrapping it again is just passing the buck. I could argue the reverse of this too. But that's why I'm looking for feedback. :)

Comment: That's indeed a fair argument but it drags us to something totally different: when you have a dependency you should also have integration tests against it, these tests should break when the contract (API) changes.

Comment: BTW, it's a good practice to have a (usually thin) wrapper around any dependency you have, adding this layer of abstraction could save you a lot of work when you decide to switch to another library for example. Second advantage, is our case - now you're mocking your wrapper - not the library!

Comment: That's a good point. This is what I was considering my wrapper class. But it might not be thin enough, which is getting me in trouble. TDD brings out better design... go figure! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Like most aspects of programming, testing requires thoughtfulness. TDD is a very useful, but certainly not sufficient, tool to help you get good tests. If you are testing thoughtfully and well, I would expect a coverage percentage in the upper 80s or 90s. I would be suspicious of anything like 100% - it would smell of someone writing tests to make the coverage numbers happy, but not thinking about what they are doing.  -- [Martin Fowler, 2012](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html)

For the core of your program, 100% coverage might be an achievable target; after all, you never introduce code without a failing test that requires is, and "refactoring" shouldn't be introducing unused branches.

But code that interacts with the boundary... 100% coverage becomes a lot more expensive, and you eventually reach the tipping point:

> I get paid for code that works, not for tests, so my philosophy is to test as little as possible to reach a given level of confidence... -- [Kent Beck, 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153565/54734)

If KeyStoreException were unchecked, you wouldn't have used this particular example; the problems of checked exceptions are somewhat unique to Java.

David Parnas, [writing in 1972](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf), gave us some hints about how we might manage this problem.  You can design your solution so that it hides your decision to use a `java.security.KeyStore`.  In other words, you create an interface that describes the API that you *wish* a keystore would have, and write all of your code to that interface.  Only the implementation needs to know the gritty details of the exception management; only your implementation needs to know that you decided that KeyStore exceptions are unrecoverable.

Another way of thinking about the same idea; we're trying to partition the code into two piles: the *core* contains complicated code that is easy to test; the *boundary* contains simple code that is difficult to test.  Your touchstone for boundary code is Hoare: "so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies".

Use test coverage heuristics that are appropriate for each case.

> My anticipated solution for now is to move my configured 90% code coverage restriction down to 40 or 50 percent until I have more classes to bring my over-all average coverage up.

Using a ratchet to prevent a regression in your coverage statistic is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

> What I've read on TDD advertises 100% code coverage.

This is a common misconception.

When we do TDD we are **not** aiming for 100% *code coverage*. We are aiming for 100% *requirement coverage*. And no: 100% code coverage does *not* imply 100% requirement coverage and vice versa...

Unfortunately we cannot measure requirement coverage. So the only way to get it is doing TDD consequently.

---

> In this particular case, according to the docs, KeyStoreException is thrown if the keyStore hasn't been initialized. I'm coding defensively and have guaranteed that the keyStore will be initialized at this point. So the KeyStoreException cannot be thrown.
>
> Given cases like this how does TDD achieve a mythical 100% coverage?
>
> I could mock KeyStore, but advice from Mockito is "Don't mock types you don't own."

UnitTests verify *your* units behavior *in isolation* which means that any other units *your* code under test collaborates with need to be replaced by  *test doubles*. There is a discussion out there at which detail level we should cut our *units* but *"types you don't own"* are definitely *not* part of *your*  code. Not mocking them means that your test depends on this external code. And if it fails you don't know if *your* code has a problem or the external code.
Therefore *"Don't mock types you don't own."* is a rather bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually TDD have nothing to do with code coverage.
One of the rule of TDD is

> You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make
>   a failing unit test pass.

So if you practicing Test-Driven Development and follow rule above then you will always have 100% code coverage.

Code coverage is measuring tool for unit testing, for case when you write tests after you wrote production code. With code coverage you "check" that you didn't forget to write test for some case in your logic.