# Mocking ScheduledExecutorService vs the "Don't mock type you don't own" philosophy

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Mocking [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) would really make testing my classes easier, but according to the [mockito recommendations](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own) this seems a bad idea, as the logic of the mocked class can change in a way that it would be used in an incorrect way, but unit tests would still report success.

It seems that writing a wrapper for it would be the "clean" way, but I have a feeling that this would merely result in the complete duplication of an interface, which would just make my code less straightforward. I'd like to follow the practical recommendations of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922861/6827729), but I am not sure that the contract of [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) will always remain the same.

Can I assume that the contract for the existing methods of [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) (or more generally, any other class in the JRE libs) will never change? If not, is it enough if I test the correct use of it in the integration tests, while still mocking it directly in the unit tests?

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService is an interface - so it is just that, a contract, and you can assume that its various implementations in the JDK follow the contract.

Comment: Thank you! But can I be sure that the interface in subsequent Java versions will specify the same contract? Just for the sake of example, suppose that a new method will be added which should be called before any call to schedule. Then my unit tests won't inform me of this change, but the software as a whole would not work properly. Or should I always stick with one version of JDK/JRE and thoroughly check everything when I upgrade?

Comment: Newer JDK versions are mostly backward compatible and the breaking changes (which more often than not are bug fixes) are clearly indicated in the release notes. If you are uncomfortable with this you can have 1 test that checks that the SES implementation works as expected (unit or integration) and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more of a guideline than a rule; do the thing that will most likely result in a clean, reliable, and non-brittle test. As in the document you quoted:

> This is not a hard line, but crossing this line may have repercussions! (it most likely will)

One important thing here is that "don't mock types you don't own" usually refers to *concrete* or *internal* types, because those are much more likely to change their behavior between versions, or to gain or lose modifiers like `final` or `static` that Mockito's dynamic overrides might not pick up on. After all, if you were to subclass a third-party class manually, Java would throw a compiler error; Mockito's syntax would hide that from you until test runtime.

To list out the factors I think of:

- As assylias pointed out in the comments, you're referring to a Java interface, which insulates you from common changes to `final` methods or method visibility.
- The interface is well-documented and designed for third-party extension, providing yet another reason that Java would be unlikely to make breaking changes to the general contract of the interface.
- The interface in question is a very well-used interface in Java, which overall has a lot of users, and a lot of backwards-compatibility concerns. It is very unlikely that you'd be subject to breaking changes, compared to a smaller library, or one under active development. One might even say that the JRE is in such lock step to the Java language, you have as much to worry about from breaking *syntax* changes than from breaking *interface* changes.

Though I believe strongly in "don't mock types you don't own" as a general heuristic or code smell, I'd agree with you here that the type is worth mocking, and that—unless you were to write and test a full implementation to be used in other tests—it's the best path forward for you here.

Comment: And this is the part I argue: *"(it most likely will)"*. As for my experience the opposite is much more likely: Your tests become brittle if you don't mock *types you don't own*...

Comment: @Timothy Okay, but in my experience, I'd agree with the Mockito docs: tests become brittle if you mock types you don't own... _if they are not interfaces designed for external subclassing_. Worse, those breakages tend to happen in really opaque ways, since Mockito can't warn about attempts to mock `final` methods or classes.

Comment: *"Mockito can't warn about attempts to mock final methods or classes."* so this is the problem: the dependency method or class became `final` with a newer version? For once: Last time I tried to mock a `final` method or class Mockito **did** complain about exactly that. For second: when did that happen to you last time in real live that a method of a dependency (your code used) changed to `final`? To me: never...

Comment: @Timothy (1) Mockito's documentation specifies that it can't detect `final` methods, for 1.x at least: ["Mockito cannot warn you about mocking final methods so be vigilant."](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito). (2) The larger the software projects you work on, the more likely you are to refer to in-house libraries under development. :) However, visibility/static/final changes join the rest of the list of contract changes that would break a cavalier Mockito-based test.

Comment: (1) *"for 1.x at least: "Mockito cannot warn you about mocking final methods"* i tried `1.9.5` (which is 5 years old) and `1.10.19` (three yeas old) and got: *Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types* maybe the doc is not up to date here...

Comment: (2a) *"The larger the software projects you work on, the more likely you are to refer to in-house libraries under development"* These *internal* dependencies have their own set of Unittests already.

Comment: (2b) *"visibility(-/static/final-) changes join the rest of the list of contract changes that would break a cavalier Mockito-based test"* Yes. But only if the changes class/Method is actually *used* in may test. In contrast if I don't mock them my test gets compile errors anyway, even if the changed method in *not used* in my tests.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the *"Don't mock type you don't own!"* is the false conclusion out of the right reasoning.

Unittests should only need to be changes if *your* API changes or the *part of an API* of a dependency *your code uses*.

example:

> You us an interface of a dependency as an input parameter, but your tested code uses only one method in that interface. If you don't mock this interface (which is a *type you don't own*) you have to create your own dummy implementation implementing all of the interfaces methods, even those you don't use.
>
> If you change the version of that dependency this interface might have additional method and/or some methods have been removed. You have to change all of *your* the implementations of this interface throughout your program. If you mocked this interface you don't need to change your tests and they still give you confidence that *your codes behavior* did not change after the required refactoring.

Furthermore your Unittest should only fail because the behavior of *your code* changed, not because of a change in the dependencies behavior.
Changes in a dependencies behavior should be pinned with separate Unittest you setup for the dependencies behavior (if it is crucial for your application) and/or *integration tests*.

Comment: Can I summarize that as "Write unit tests for anything you mock, be it your own or someone else's class"? In other words, does that mean that I should write a unit test for external classes which I use (in my case, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor), regardless of the fact that they also may have unit tests in the project they are developed in?

It is interesting, because in this case, if my unit test for an external class would fail, that would mean that I would have to modify the behaviour of my own classes, whose unit tests ran successfully.

Comment: @AlbertP *"Can I summarize that as "Write unit tests for anything you mock, be it your own or someone else's class"?"* No. Only if you have doubt that the behavior you depend on may change in a way that affects the correctness of your application. As for my experience usually this is not the case.