# Mockito: how to mock a static method with parameters and void return type without of invocation of real method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, mocking, mockito

In other words:

> How to use "doAnswer" stubbing for static mocks in mockito?

I didn't find a way to do it. I found only the "when(...).then(...)" way to stub static methods.

For Example:

I want to linearize method `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` (Why? I want it simple :-)).

Using the latest Mockito I can mock static methods and write somthing like this (in try-with-resource block of course):

```java
Answer<Object> directInvocationAnswer = invocation -> {
    ((Runnable) invocation.getArgument(0)).run();
    return null;
};
MockedStatic<SwingUtilities> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SwingUtilities.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
mockedStatic.when(() -> SwingUtilities.invokeLater(any(Runnable.class))).then(directInvocationAnswer);
```

It works, but I can see a NPE in the event queue. It doesn't work. At all.

It is understandable, because `() -> SwingUtilities.invokeLater(any(Runnable.class))` invokes real `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` with `null` as parameter (`any()` returns `null`) and mockito can't stop the real invocation, because it does not known (at this point in time) - is is a "normal" invocation in production code or a stubbing invocation.

And I can't remove `CALLS_REAL_METHODS`, because I want to use other methods of the class.

Yes, I can trick mockito and avoid calling of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(null)`:

```java
Answer<Object> directInvocationAnswer = invocation -> {
    ((Runnable) invocation.getArgument(0)).run();
    return null;
};
MockedStatic<SwingUtilities> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SwingUtilities.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
any(Runnable.class); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
mockedStatic.when(() ->
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MyUtils::nop)) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   .then(directInvocationAnswer);
return mockedStatic;
```

It works here, but it's very ugly und it does not work in all cases - the real method was invoked at least once.

Are there any ways to use `doAnswer`-like stubbing for static mocks in mockito?

Comment: Can't you just use 2 variables of type MockedStatic, one with parameter CALLS_REAL_METHODS and other one without it?

Comment: No, it does not work - Mockito does not allowed two static mocks for the same class and throws an exception.

Comment: so: you want to "intercept" `null` parameters (of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`) *only*, and call real method for non-null's, right?

Comment: you misunderstand/-spell (at least) two things: 1. `any()` *never returns* `null` (but matches it), `any(Runnable.class)` even *never matches* `null`. 2.: With "...avoid calling of SwingUtilities.invokeLater(null)", you don't trick mockito, but is "just good"! :-)

Comment: [PowerMockito](https://javadoc.io/static/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.7.4/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html) (esp. the "introduction" & `mockStatic`, maybe `doNothing/callRealMethod` parts) , [Matchers](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html), [Settings](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockSettings.html), [Answers](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockSettings.html)

Comment: (version 4.2.0) fixed links: [Answers](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.2.0/org/mockito/Answers.html) , [Settings](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.2.0/org/mockito/MockSettings.html)

Comment: @xerx593
Thank you for your answer, but to avoid misunderstanding:

1. I want to stub `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` (and only this method in `SwingUtilities`, other should work) without calling of real method. 
Using `Answer` and `Settings` I can change default answer, but I want to have CALLS_REAL_METHODS for other methods.

2. `any()` always returns `null` (for non-primitive types), just because it must return something :-)

3. Yes, with PowerMock it works, but PowerMock is slower and difficult to use in compare with Mockito. I want use Mockito :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would not mock `SwingUtilities` at all. A general rule for mocking is "[don't mock what don't own](https://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t%20mock%20what%20you%20don%27t%20own)". I would wrap the calls to `SwingUtilities` into a separate class with non-static methods and inject an instance of that class. Then you can easily mock the wrapper class without the static-mock crutch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1906344/592355 : The votes (as me) tend rather to "why not!?" ;)

Comment: ..and in car/air or fashion industry (e.g.), this NEVER holds! :-)

Comment: If you feel the urge to mock what you do not own, this means your business code is directly depending on that code, which is a bad idea. Business code should never depend on concrete technical details. In this case his code depends directly on Swing. I would define an interface `ThreadDispatcher` with a method `invokeLater()` and an implementation `SwingThreadDispatcher` which calls `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and inject this for the interface. This way the business code does not depend on Swing anymore (at least not via `SwingUtilities`).

Comment: I know it is possible to mock pretty much everyhing these days, but that does not mean it is a good idea.

Comment: I get you, @Eric, and understand the articles & objections, but I would go further (than why not!) and postulate:  the (most) motivation/purpose/right to exist of "mocking" is the "desire to control" things which you "not own"/over which you have no control!  (Time, temperature, network(!!!), "database", (GUI!), "does not yet exist or may change behavior"). The only "excuse" for "mocking own things" is: you don't want to change your (own, real) things for test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Comment: That's why your business code should depend on interfaces for all technical details instead of depending on the concrete implementations. The wrapper is then only needed because the code you do not own does usually not implement your interface, except for languages that have implicit interface impementation like golang.
The point I am trying to make is, that your business code should not depend on Swing or any other frameworks, databases, filesystems etc. at all. Mocking code you do not own means that is does in fact depend on such a techicality.

Comment: @EricSchaefer
1. May be you have right. For new code. If you have old legacy code, you need to write unit tests **before** refactoring. In this case it is sometimes helpfully to mock SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

2. I use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` only as example. I want to find a way, to stub **only one** static method without calling of real method (and all other static method should be real invoked).